# Does react-native-device-info `getUniqueId()` give UUID or GUID?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uuid, guid, react-native-device-info

In my React Native app, I have to pass a unique ID to an API endpoint, and I've been told that it has to be a GUID. What I want to know is:

1) Does the `getUniqueId()` method in `react-native-device-info` give a GUID?

2) I've seen another module `react-native-create-guid`. It says that it "creates" a GUID. I thought that the device automatically has a GUID associated with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUID/UUID is not a device ID. It is a [standard of a unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) that is statistically unlikely to be duplicated. GUIDs are used virtually everywhere, and not only when you need to identify a device. `react-native-create-guid` is a general-purpose library unrelated to the device identification domain.

As for the device ID, can be a GUID/UUID, or it can be something else – any random string. It is up to the device manufacturer and standards imposed by the platform. If I remember correctly, on Android the Device ID is not guaranteed to be a GUID at all. On iOS, on the other hand, the device ID is indeed a UUID. The identifier is called "IDFV" and it is generated in a peculiar way – see [Apple's documentation for more details](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor?language=objc).

You need to talk with your backend engineer to clarify the requirements.

Comment: Perfect, this helped me resolve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I helped!